# how to calculate two column in sql using JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, database, laravel

so I have table in sql with 20 columns and I need one column to get the sum of other two columns, the data is showing in `modal-fade` dialog this is how it look like

```
div id="show" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                  </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="">Previous Violations :</label>
                      <b id="st_pv"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="">Current Violation :</label>
                      <b id="st_cv"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="">Total Violations :</label>
                      <b id="st_tv"/>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the button in the table that trigger the `modal-fade` dialog

```
<td>
            <a class="show-modal btn btn-info btn-sm" 
            data-prev_violation="'.$row->prev_violation.'" 
            data-curr_violation="'.$row->curr_violation.'"
            data-tota_violation="'.$row->tota_violation.'"
            >
              <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
            </a>
          </td>
```

and this is the `JQuery` that displays data on the `modal-fade` dialog

```
  // Show function
  $(document).on('click', '.show-modal', function() {
  $('#show').modal('show');

  $('#st_pv').text($(this).data('prev_violation'));
  $('#st_cv').text($(this).data('curr_violation'));
  $('#st_tv').text($(this).data('prev_violation+curr_violation'));
  $('#st_n').text($(this).data('student_name'));
  $('#st_co').text($(this).data('course'));

  $('.modal-title').text('Student Details');
  });
```

this was my attempt to get the sum of two columns   `$('#st_tv').text($(this).data('prev_violation+curr_violation'));` when I replace it with the column name `tota_violation` it displays the result stored in sql, but I need calculation of two columns, please help

Comment: Since you are in a blade view is it not possible to do `$row->prev_violation + $row->curr_violation` where you need the total?

Comment: @Donkarnash I tried that but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probaly want to do something like this:

```
$('#st_tv').text(
  $(this).data('prev_violation') + $(this).data('curr_violation')
);
```

The `.data` method retreives **ONE** data-attribute value. The math can be done inside the `.text()` method to update the DOM when the result is calculated.

Comment: *"Those are text"*. Not entirely accurate. data() will parse json or numeric string values to appropriate type

Comment: Agreed @charlietfl. But here, I assume that OP is echoing the value in the attribute... ;)

Comment: That's what I mean though... when it is in attribute data() will parse to appropriate type . Example: https://jsfiddle.net/4gy5e1ds/

Comment: Wow! I really didn't know that! Thanks @charlietfl

Comment: I wish I can understand what you guys saying:( im php noob lol

Comment: @FathiDraws, we were talking about the [jQuery .data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.